# How to animate to anchors when using jquery smint plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, anchor

I am trying to animate to anchors when visiting the page from external links, currently it jumps and then goes back to the top. I am using the jquery smint sticky nav plugin and I think it is conflicting with the window load function. I need to be able to link to the different sections externally using a # in the link.

**Example link:** http://www.somesite/somepage#sect2

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="subMenu" >
        <div class="inner">
            <a href="#" id="s1" class="subNavBtn active">link</a> 
            <a href="#" id="s2" class="subNavBtn trek">link</a>
            <a href="#" id="s3" class="subNavBtn hike">link</a>
            <a href="#" id="s4" class="subNavBtn new">link</a>
        </div>  
  </div>

<div class="section sTop">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="images/01_header.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="sect1" class="section s1">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="images/02_walk.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="sect2" class="section s2">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="images/03_hike.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="sect3" class="section s3">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="images/04_trek.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="sect4" class="section s4">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="images/05_new.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0;}


body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
    background:#bfbfbf;


}


h1, h2 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin:0 0 15px 0;
}


h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    line-height: 100%;
}

h1.title {
    font-size: 46px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #6a6a6a;


}


h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.menuBtn {

    background: center center no-repeat transparent;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;

}

.active {
    background: #3B5323;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.wrap {
        width: 944px;
        z-index: 10;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;

}

.section {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 944px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}


.inner {
    width: 944px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
}

.subMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 793px;
    z-index: 1000;
    min-width: 944px;
    height: 100px;
}

.subMenu .inner {
    padding:0;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.subNavBtn {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: -4000px;
}

.end {
    margin: 0;
}


/* SECTIONS */
.sTop {
    height: 793px;
}

.s1 {
    height: 1983px
}


.s2 {
    height: 1883px
}


.s3 {
    height: 1883px
}


.s4 {
    height: 1883px
}

.s5 {
    height: 1725px;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
(function(){


    $.fn.smint = function( options ) {

        // adding a class to users div
        $(this).addClass('smint')

        var settings = $.extend({
                    'scrollSpeed '  : 500
        }, options);

        //Set the variables needed
        var optionLocs = new Array();
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        var menuHeight = $(".smint").height();

        return $('.smint a').each( function(index) {

            if ( settings.scrollSpeed ) {
                var scrollSpeed = settings.scrollSpeed
            }

            //Fill the menu
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            optionLocs.push(Array($("div."+id).position().top-menuHeight, $("div."+id).height()+$("div."+id).position().top, id));

            ///////////////////////////////////

            // get initial top offset for the menu 
            var stickyTop = $('.smint').offset().top;   

            // check position and make sticky if needed
            var stickyMenu = function(direction){

                // current distance top
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 

                // if we scroll more than the navigation, change its position to fixed and add class 'fxd', otherwise change it back to absolute and remove the class
                if (scrollTop > stickyTop) { 
                    $('.smint').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0 }).addClass('fxd');  
                } else {
                    $('.smint').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top':stickyTop }).removeClass('fxd'); 
                }   

                //Check if the position is inside then change the menu
                // Courtesy of Ryan Clarke (@clarkieryan)



                if(optionLocs[index][0] <= scrollTop && scrollTop <= optionLocs[index][1]){ 
                    if(direction == "up"){
                        $("#"+id).addClass("active");
                        $("#"+optionLocs[index+1][2]).removeClass("active");
                    } else if(index > 0) {
                        $("#"+id).addClass("active");
                        $("#"+optionLocs[index-1][2]).removeClass("active");
                    } else if(direction == undefined){
                        $("#"+id).addClass("active");
                    }
                    $.each(optionLocs, function(i){
                        if(id != optionLocs[i][2]){
                            console.log(i);
                            $("#"+optionLocs[i][2]).removeClass("active");
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            // run functions
            stickyMenu();

            // run function every time you scroll
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                //Get the direction of scroll
                var st = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (st > lastScrollTop) {
                    direction = "down";
                } else if (st < lastScrollTop ){
                    direction = "up";
                }
                lastScrollTop = st;
                stickyMenu(direction);

                // Check if at bottom of page, if so, add class to last <a> as sometimes the last div
                // isnt long enough to scroll to the top of the page and trigger the active state.

                if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                $('.smint a').removeClass('active')
                $('.smint a').last().addClass('active')
   }
            });

            ///////////////////////////////////////


            $(this).on('click', function(e){
                // gets the height of the users div. This is used for off-setting the scroll so the menu doesnt overlap any content in the div they jst scrolled to
                var selectorHeight = $('.smint').height();   

                // stops empty hrefs making the page jump when clicked
                e.preventDefault();

                // get id pf the button you just clicked
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

                // if the link has the smint-disable class it will be ignored 
                // Courtesy of mcpacosy ‏(@mcpacosy)

                if ($(this).hasClass("smint-disable"))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                // gets the distance from top of the div class that matches your button id minus the height of the nav menu. This means the nav wont initially overlap the content.
                var goTo =  $('div.'+ id).offset().top -selectorHeight;

                // Scroll the page to the desired position!
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: goTo }, scrollSpeed);

            }); 
        });
    }


})();


$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.subMenu').smint({
        'scrollSpeed' : 500
    });
});

$(window).bind("load", function () {
          var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('a[href="#' + urlHash + '"]').offset().top -40}, 300);
      });
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I improved smint a little bit. This should help you.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SMINT | The simple jQuery plugin for lovers of one page websites.</title>

<meta name = "keywords" content = "SMINT jQuery Plugin, SMINT, jQuery Plugin, One Page Website, Sticky Navigation" />
<meta name = "description" content = "SMINT is a simple plugin for lovers of one page websites, which helps with sticky menus and page scrolling." />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">


<link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.smint.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.subMenu').smint({
        'scrollSpeed'           : 500,
        'mySelector'            : 'div',
        'lastSectionBigEnough'  : 0 // 1 = big enough to trigger activ on scroll, 0 = not big enough, active is triggerd after reaching the bottom
    });
});


$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0); 
});

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap ">
    <div class="section sTop">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1 class="title">SMINT Demo Page</h1>
            <h2 class="subtitle">Feel free to use this as your starting template</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="subMenu" >
        <div class="inner">
            <a href="#sTop" class="subNavBtn">Home</a>
            <a href="#s1" class="subNavBtn">Section 1</a> 
            <a href="#s2" class="subNavBtn">Section 2</a>
            <a href="#s3" class="subNavBtn">Section 3</a>
            <a href="#s4" class="subNavBtn">Section 4</a>
            <a href="#s5" class="subNavBtn">Section 5</a>
            <a href="http://www.grasenhiller.de" class="subNavBtn extLink">Grasenhiller</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="s1" class="section s1">
        <div class="inner ">
            <h1>Section 1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="s2" class="section s2">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1>Section 2</h1>
            <p><a href="#s4" class="intLink">Internal Link: Jump to Section 4</a></p>
            <p><a href="#sTop" class="intLink">Internal Link: Back to Top</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="s3" class="section s3">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1>Section 3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="s4" class="section s4">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1>Section 4</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="s5" class="section s5">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1>Section 5</h1>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

jquery.smint.js

```
    /*
SMINT V3.0 by robert McCracken with some awesome help from Ryan Clarke (@clarkieryan) and mcpacosy ‏(@mcpacosy)
*/

(function(){

    $.fn.smint = function( options ) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            'scrollSpeed'           : 500,
            'mySelector'            : 'div',
            'lastSectionBigEnough'  : 0 // 1 = big enough to trigger activ on scroll, 0 = not big enough, active is triggerd after reaching the bottom
        }, options);

        // adding a class to users div
        $(this).addClass('smint');

        //Set the variables needed
        var optionLocs = new Array();
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        var menuHeight = $(".smint").height();
        var smint = $('.smint');
        var smintA = $('.smint a');
        var myOffset = smint.height();
        var myClickOffset = menuHeight-5;

        if ( settings.scrollSpeed ) {
            var scrollSpeed = settings.scrollSpeed
        }

        if ( settings.mySelector ) {
            var mySelector = settings.mySelector
        }

        if ( settings.lastSectionBigEnough ) {
            var lastSectionBigEnough = settings.lastSectionBigEnough
        }

        return smintA.each( function(index) { 
            var id = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];

            if (!$(this).hasClass("extLink")) {
                $(this).attr('data-jumpto', id);
            }

            // Fill the menu
            if (!$(this).hasClass("extLink")) {
                var extLink = 0;
            } else {
                var extLink = 1;
            }

            if(! extLink ){
                optionLocs.push(Array(
                    $(mySelector+"."+id).position().top-menuHeight, 
                    $(mySelector+"."+id).height()+$(mySelector+"."+id).position().top, id)
                );
            }

            // get initial top offset for the menu 
            var stickyTop = smint.offset().top; 

            // check position and make sticky if needed
            var stickyMenu = function(direction,extLink){

                // current distance top
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()+myOffset; 

                // if we scroll more than the navigation, change its position to fixed and add class 'fxd', otherwise change it back to absolute and remove the class
                if (scrollTop > stickyTop+myOffset) { 
                    smint.css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0,'left':0 }).addClass('fxd');

                    // add padding to the body to make up for the loss in heigt when the menu goes to a fixed position.
                    // When an item is fixed, its removed from the flow so its height doesnt impact the other items on the page
                    $('body').css('padding-top', menuHeight );  
                } else {
                    smint.css( 'position', 'relative').removeClass('fxd'); 
                    //remove the padding we added.
                    $('body').css('padding-top', '0' ); 
                }   

                // Check if the position is inside then change the menu
                // Courtesy of Ryan Clarke (@clarkieryan)
                if(! extLink ){
                    if(optionLocs[index][0] <= scrollTop && scrollTop <= optionLocs[index][1]){ 
                        if(direction == "up"){
                            $('.smint a').removeClass("active");
                            $('.smint a[data-jumpto="'+id+'"]').addClass("active");
                        } else if(index >= 0) {
                            $('.smint a').removeClass("active");
                            $('.smint a[data-jumpto="'+id+'"]').addClass("active");
                        } else if(direction == undefined){
                            $('.smint a[data-jumpto="'+id+'"]').addClass("active");
                        }
                        $.each(optionLocs, function(i){
                            if(id != optionLocs[i][2]){

                                $('.smint a[data-jumpto="'+optionLocs[i][2]+'"]').removeClass("active");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };

            // run functions
            stickyMenu(null,extLink);

            // run function every time you scroll
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                //Get the direction of scroll
                var st = $(this).scrollTop()+myOffset;
                if (st > lastScrollTop) {
                    direction = "down";
                } else if (st < lastScrollTop ){
                    direction = "up";
                }
                lastScrollTop = st;
                stickyMenu(direction,extLink);

                // Check if at bottom of page, if so, add class to last <a> as sometimes the last div
                // isnt long enough to scroll to the top of the page and trigger the active state.
                if(!lastSectionBigEnough){
                    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                        smintA.removeClass('active')
                        $(".smint a:not('.extLink'):last").addClass('active')

                    } else {
                        smintA.last().removeClass('active')
                    }
                }
            });

            $(this).on('click', function(e){
                if(! extLink ){
                    // gets the height of the users div. This is used for off-setting the scroll so the menu doesnt overlap any content in the div they jst scrolled to
                    var myOffset = myClickOffset;

                    // stops hrefs making the page jump when clicked
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // get the hash of the button you just clicked
                    var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];

                    var goTo =  $(mySelector+'.'+ hash).offset().top-myOffset;

                    // Scroll the page to the desired position!
                    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: goTo }, scrollSpeed);
                }

            }); 

            //This lets yo use links in body text to scroll. Just add the class 'intLink' to your button and it will scroll
            $('.intLink').on('click', function(e){
                var myOffset = myClickOffset;  

                e.preventDefault();

                var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];

                if (smint.hasClass('fxd')) {
                    var goTo =  $(mySelector+'.'+ hash).position().top-myOffset;
                } else {
                    var goTo =  $(mySelector+'.'+ hash).position().top-myOffset*2;
                }

                $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: goTo }, scrollSpeed);

                if ($(this).hasClass("extLink")) {
                    return false;
                }

            }); 
        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```